# Getting error 500 even after using async in react native with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

While creating a signup page I am getting error.
My auth code is

```
const createUser=async()=>{
        await auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User account created & signed in!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
      console.log('That email address is already in use!');
    }

    if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
      console.log('That email address is invalid!');
    }

    console.error(error);
  });
    }
```

What I am getting is :

```
 Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins
```

the file I was editing into is SignupScreen.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSHrS.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!